# $x\hat{f}(x)\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ implies $x\hat{f}(x)\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $\hat{f}(x)=\int_\mathbb{R}f(t)e^{-itx}dt$ be the Fourier transform of the function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

If $\hat{f}$ has bounded derivative on $\mathbb{R}$ and $$x\hat{f}(x)\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$$ can we say that $$x\hat{f}(x)\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})?$$

Comment: That is correct, $\hat f$ is not only continuous, but also differentiable. Somehow the boundedness of $f$ should be used to prevent substantial spikes at infinity in $\hat f$, atm I do not see how.

Comment: Rudin RCA chapter 9 exercise 5 provides a useful result for our situation.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\phi \in C^\infty_c(-1,0)$ and $$\hat{f} = \sum_{n\ge 1} n \, 2^{-2n}\phi(2^{n} (x-2^{2n}))$$

- $\hat{f}$ is $L^1$ so $f$ is $L^\infty$
- $\hat{f}' = \sum_{n\ge 1}n 2^{-n} \phi'(2^n (x-2^{2n}))$ is $L^\infty$
- Both $\hat{f},\hat{f}'$ are $L^2$ so $f,xf$ and $(1+|x|)f$ are $L^2$ whence $f$ is $L^1$ (Cauchy Schwarz)
- $\|x\hat{f}\|_{L^1}\le \sum_{n\ge 1} \|n\phi(2^n (x-2^{2n}))\|_{L^1}=
  \sum_{n\ge 1} n 2^{-n} \|\phi\|_{L^1}< \infty$
- $x\hat{f}$ is not $L^\infty$

Comment: $x\hat f(x)$ appears to be bounded by about $1$ since for any $x$, at most one summand of the series is nonzero. Perhaps it can be modified by replacing $2^{-n}$ in front by $n2^{-n}$?

Comment: Right I don't know what I was thinking to

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Please check my repair :-)

Comment: I'm having some trouble verifying $f\in L^1$ based on $f,xf\in L^2$... It seems maybe you need something more like $(1+|x|)f\in L^2$ instead of $xf\in L^2$? Since otherwise Cauchy-Schwarz leaves $\int x^{-2} = +\infty$ (assuming I've understood how you wanted to apply CS).

Comment: Yes that's the point $f,xf\in L^2$ does give that $(1+|x|) f \in L^2$ so $\|f\|_{L^1}\le \|\frac1{1+|x|}\|_{L^2} \|(1+|x|)f\|_{L^2}$ @AlexOrtiz

Comment: Whoops, of course it does! Looks good to me!